# How to automatically stop YouTube video outside the viewport?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am making a simple one-page website which has the YouTube embeded video on it. When a visitor plays a video and then scrolls the page, and video is not in the viewport any more, the video should stop. The code I built is producing an error:

```
TypeError: player is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

player.stopVideo();
```

Here is the iframe code:

```
<iframe id="player" width="1280" height="720" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/prN2lxPBSxc?rel=0enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Here is the Javascript (inside `<head></head>`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onscroll = function () {
            var player;
            function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
                var player = new YT.Player('player');
            }
            var height = $(window).height();
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            var obj = $("#video-bellow-team");
            var pos = obj.position();
            if (height + scrollTop < pos.top) {
               player.stopVideo();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

It seems that `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady();` is never executed, don't know why. I found somewhere that it should be on window object, I tried it, but the result is the same.

Please advise.

Thnaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example, i couldnt use jsfiddle since webserver is needed.

http://f.cl.ly/items/3t0Q3y2n231G1J2E240G/test1.html

http://cl.ly/code/1l260V1j0j0Y

here is the source code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #video1 {
        margin-top: 50px;
        display: block;
    }
    .text {
        width: 900px;
        display: block;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- create a div that will be video container -->
    <div id="video1"></div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    var obj = $("#video1");
    var pos = obj.position();

    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        // video1 must be the div #id of the video container
        player = new YT.Player('video1', {
            height: '315',
            width: '560',
            videoId: 'prN2lxPBSxc',
            playerVars: {
                controls: 0,
                showinfo: 0,
                modestbranding: 1,
                wmode: "opaque"
            },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });
    };

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        $(document).on('scroll', function() {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scrollTop > pos.top + 315) {
                player.stopVideo();
            }
        })
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and built on top of it. I got your script to autoplay the youtube video when in view, and stop the video when it is above and below the viewport.

http://www.goldrushcoinsandjewelry.com//_assets/files/video-scroll-5.html

(view the source code and copy/paste)

All I did was modify the "onPlayerReady" function:

```
        if (scrollTop < pos.top + 15) {
            player.playVideo();
        }
        if (scrollTop > pos.top + 315) {
            player.stopVideo();
        }
        if (scrollTop < pos.top - 315) {
            player.stopVideo();
        }
```

Hope someone finds this useful.